# Python - Problems with my loop and print out format

Tags: python

I am trying to let a user keep entering module and grades and store it as a dictionary {module:grades} and store this dictionary in a list.

I have 3 issues in this.

1. I am unable to use F6 in the second raw_input which is F7.
2. Secondly, I am using 'done' to stop the loop. When I print the information it looks like this:

{done : 100}
{done : 80}

and so on.. So the module name keeps getting replaced by the word 'done'.

1. And lastly I am trying to make the print out appear as follows: (which is not hapening now..)

Grades: Computer Science: 100
Computer Graphics: 80

I have finished the rest of my work less this portion which I am stuck with. Any assistance is deeply appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
students = []

class Student:
    grades = {}

    def setGrades(self, grades):
        self.grades = grades

    def addStudent():
        while F6 != 'done':
            F6 = raw_input("Please enter module name. type 'done' to quit: ")
            if F6 == 'done':
                break
            F7 = raw_input("Please enter the grades for " ,F6, ':')


student.setGrades({F6:F7})
```

Comment: You need to properly indent your code, indents are meaningful in python.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your code (as is) should look something like this

```
students = []

class Student:
    grades = {}

    def setGrades(self, grades):
        self.grades = grades

    def addStudent():
        while True:
            F6 = raw_input("Please enter module name. type 'done' to quit: ")
            if F6 == 'done':
                break
            F7 = raw_input("Please enter the grades for " ,F6, ':')
            student.setGrades({F6:F7})
```

In my opinion you should also have a better api for setting Grades. Something like this would suffice imo:

```
def set_grades(self, lesson, grade):
    self.grades[lesson] = grade
```

Finally in order to print the grades you should have a method like this:

```
def print_grades(self):
    for lesson, grade in grades.items():
        print lesson, grade
```

Last but not least in your raw input, in order to use F6 you have to do something like that:

```
F7 = raw_input("Please enter the grades for %s: " % F6)
```

To sum it all up, if I were you my code would look something like this:

```
class Student:
    grades = {}

    def set_grades(self, lesson, grade):
        self.grades[lesson] = grade

    def addStudent():
        while True:
            F6 = raw_input("Please enter module name. type 'done' to quit: ")
            if F6 == 'done':
                break
            F7 = raw_input("Please enter the grades for %s: " % F6)
            student.setGrades(F6, F7)

    def print_grades(self):
        for lesson, grade in grades.items():
            print lesson, grade
```